# how to Serialization of class contains others class object

Tags: serialization

```
   [Serializable()]
    public class Transmission
    {
        [XmlElement("DiagnosisErrorResponse")]
        public DiagnosisErrorResponse DiagnosisErrorResponse { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class DiagnosisErrorResponse
    {
        [XmlElement("ID")]
        public long ID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ErrorCode")]
        public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ErrorDescription")]
        public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ErrorDate")]
        public string ErrorDate { get; set; }
        public Transmission[] trans;
    }
```